# Symfony2 Form - Event listener on Embed Form

Tags: forms, symfony, symfony-2.3

Starting from the example in the symfony cookbook about dynamic form generation ([link to doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#cookbook-form-events-submitted-data))

```
class SportMeetupType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('sport', 'entity', array(...))
        ;

        $builder->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,
            function(FormEvent $event) {
                $form = $event->getForm();

                // this would be your entity, i.e. SportMeetup
                $data = $event->getData();

                $positions = $data->getSport()->getAvailablePositions();

                $form->add('position', 'entity', array('choices' => $positions));
            }
        );
    }
}
```

I reproduced this code with a difference, I embed this form in a parent form (called for the exemple `SportPlayerType`).

`SportPlayerType` is mapped on entity `SportPlayer` which contains a couple of attributes : $name and $meetup, a string and a SportMeetup.

My problem is in the lambda function, parameter of the addEventListener :

- `$event->getForm()` returns the child form SportMeetupType
- `$event->getData()` returns the parent mapped entity SportPlayer

As a result, `$form->add('position')` throw an error because the FormBuilder cannot match `position` field on entity SportPlayer.

How could I force matching between SportMeetupType and entity SportMeetup when SportMeetupType in an embed form?

Comment: I usually just use a subscriber class so I'm not sure if this is the problem.  The listener will get called twice.  You should have a if !$data) return in there.  And you might consider making a subscriber class though it really should not make any difference.

Comment: You should be able to access the embedded form.  `$form->get('sport')`, assuming that it what this form is doing.

Comment: @Flosculus I already tried this solution, but the problem is not the form, it is the entity accessed from `$event->getData()`

Answer (score 1):

We'll there is a reason the event is called `PRE_SET_DATA` ...

Namely the event gets fired **before** the submitted data is set.

Therefore you can't access ...

```
$event->getData()->getSport();
```

... in the listener as long as you don't provide a `new Sport()` object or an existing entity when creating the form i.e. in a controller like this:

```
$entity = new Sport(); // ... or get the entity from db
$form = $this->createForm(new SportMeetupType(), $entity);
```

Just use the `POST_SET_DATA` [event](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Form/FormEvents.php#L16) and the data will be available.

Comment: I tried this :

    `$player = new SportPlayer();`
    `$player->setSportMeetup(new SportMeetup());`
    `$form = $this->createForm(new SportPlayerType(), $player);`

But the result is the same on `PRE_SET_DATA` and `POST_SET_DATA` events :

Neither the property "position" nor one of the methods "getPosition()", "isPosition()", "hasPosition()", "__get()" or "__call()" exist and have public access in class "SportPlayer"

Comment: Well can you confirm that your `SportPlayer` class indeed does have a method `getPosition()` that returns the `$position` property ?

Comment: No. `SportPlayer` have a method `getSportMeetup()` returning a `SportMeetup`. `SportMeetup` have a method `getposition()`. This is the problem, data in the `Event` is a SportPlayer, but the form in the `Event` is mapped on the SportMeetup.

Comment: Then call `$event->getData->getSportMeetup()->getPosition()` ... and make sure you have `$this->sportMeetup = new SportMeetup();` in the `__construct()` method of your `SportPlayer` class!

Comment: The error occurs when, in the `EventListener`, I add a new field in my form `$form->add('position')`. I know how to access to the `position` threw the `SportMeetup` getter, but how can I tell symfony to do the same on form creation ? Maybe it will be clearer if I tell you I tried, as a solution, to set the `property_path` of the `position` field to `'sportMeetup/position'`...